# Помогите создать триггер в SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, триггер

Есть две таблицы:

1-ая:

```
id   name   count   summ
1   obj1    X1      Y1
2   obj2    X2      Y2
3   obj3    X3      Y3
```

и 2-ая:

```
id   objects summ
1   obj1     50
2   obj1     75
3   obj2     66
4   obj1     40
```

И собственно вопрос:

Можно ли с помощью триггера в БД сделать обновление `Х1`, `Х2`, `Х3` (количество записей `obj1`, `obj2` etc во второй таблице) и `Y1`, `Y2`, `Y3` (сумма значений summ соответствующих обьектов).

То есть, выбрать из второй таблицы количество записей `obj1` и записать в первую таблицу для `obj1`, ну и аналогично с суммой для каждого обьекта. Событие для триггера - добавление или удаление записей из второй таблицы...

Comment: Выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скрипты для таблиц, изменяющий запрос, требуемое финальное состояние таблиц для показанных данных и запроса.

Comment: Во вторую таблицу добавляется 1 строка, после этого в первой таблице надо обновить количество строк с этим именем и сумму значений

Comment: Это и так понятно. Да, кстати, триггер нужен активный (каждый раз считает заново по всему массиву данных) или корректирующий (корректирует суммарные данные на основании изменения исходных)? Первый медленнее, второй может приводить к неверным данным.

Comment: скорее всего активный, т.к. строк не будет огромное количество и скорость работы не критична

Answer (score 0):

Корректирующий триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_t2
AFTER INSERT
ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table1
SET table1.count = table1.count + 1,
    table1.summ = table1.summ + NEW.summ
WHERE table1.name = NEW.object;
```

и аналогичный триггер на DELETE.

---

Активный триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_t2
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
ON table2
UPDATE table1
SET table1.count = new_data.count,
    table1.summ = new_data.summ
FROM ( SELECT table2.object, COUNT(table2.object) count, SUM(table2.summ) summ
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY table2.object ) new_data
WHERE table1.name = new_data.object;
```

---

PS. Оба триггера предполагают, что все поля в `table2` определены как NOT NULL.